# Folder name not appearing on top of the Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I do not know what's wrong - I have a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit edition, all of a sudden the Windows Explorer has stopped displaying the name of the Folder at the top (in the title bar). Here is a snapshot of it:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the same as mine, is the snap shot a image of what it looks like now or used to look like?

Comment: it's what it looks like now.

Comment: Previously there used to be name of the folder, (in this case - "Back to the Future") used to written at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have been using the classic theme before because with the Aero theme (what is shown in the picture) Windows 7 doesn't show any title in the title bar area.

In order to change you need to

1. Right click the desktop and choose Personalize
2. Click on Windows Classic Theme

Comment: I have not changed any setting/theme, all of a sudden the title disappeared.

Comment: I can confirm that by design, the Windows 7 Aero theme **does not** display any text in Windows Explorer's title bar.

Answer (score 0):

[ShellFolderFix utility](http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html) allows to display the folder name even under Aero.

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to provide a link to what you are referring to or include some more information in your answer.